# How to catch exception (caused in C++) in python

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I want to embed python in my C++ application. I don't to use Boost library.

If C++ function throws an exception, I want to catch it and print error in my application or get some detailed information like line number in python script that caused error.

How can I do it? I can't find any functions to get detailed exception information in Python API or C++.

```
void sum(int iA, int iB)
{
    throw iA + iB;
}

from ctypes import * 

mydll = WinDLL("C:\\Users\\cppwrapper.dll")

try:
    mydll.sum(2,3)
catch:
    print "exception occured"
```

but it is not working. Please help me in sorting out this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is to catch the exception in your C++ function and then convert it to a python exception and return that to the python code (see [the manual](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#intermezzo-errors-and-exceptions) for details). Something like:

```
PyObject method(...)
{
     try {
          res = do_stuff();
          return res;
     }
     catch(SomeException e)
     {
          PyErr_SetObject(exception_type, message);
          return NULL;
     }
     catch(...)
     {
          PyErr_SetObject(PyErr_SystemError, "Unexpected exception in C++");
          return NULL;
     }
}
```

If you don't catch the exception before returning to python the exception would probably fall through the python interpreter and maybe drop out to the C++ function that called the python interpreter. That would probably be a bad way to handle the exception since the python interpreter wouldn't be able to do clean up. The ellipsis catch is just to make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, I ve few quiries. catch(SomeException e) , is this SomeException  is defined in C++ or Python?

Comment: It's C++, the point is that C++ and Python exception handling are not the same or compatible. You'll have to translate from a C++ exception to a python exception and that's what the example is about. The python interpreter will interpret a C extension returning `NULL` instead of an object as if an exception has been thrown (and the exception is stored in a global variable that is set by `PyErr_SetObject`).

Comment: What to do in a case where I'm using outside library where I don't have access to ++ source code but I want to catch c++ exceptions in Python so it doesn't crash python interpreter?

Comment: @Daniel Then I'd suggest you write a wrapper very much like the one above. You probably need to anyway unless the code is already adapted for python (in which case it should convert the exception to start with).

Comment: @Daniel In the sample `do_stuff` could have been in third-party code where you don't have the source code. Normally you would have to convert `res` to a python object too if `do_stuff` doesn't return a `PyObject`.

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I had to change e.g. PyErr_SystemError to PyExc_RuntimeError, and the message needed to be wrapped in a Python object, e.g. PyUnicode_FromString(msg), in order to get it to compile. But I still don't get any errors raised in Python.

Comment: Ahh maybe it is the NULL, I am not returning that probably. Without this the exception handling won't be triggered?